# How to refer to a method of a class?

Tags: objective-c, class, methods

I have a problem when using qsort。

```
qsort(ArrayToSort, size_a, size_b, FunctionPointer);
```

If  FunctionPointer is declared as int (* FunctionPointer)(); then it's fine.

If FunctionPointer is declared as  `FunctionPointer ＝ @selector(MyMethod);` then I have run time error of BAD_ACCESS。

Here MyMethod is my own class method，

```
int MyMethod(const void *,const void *);
```

Please advise me. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a class method for a comparison. Just declare a regular C function and pass that.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're trying to mix C code with Obj-C code. `@selector(someMethod:)` returns a `SEL` which is neither a C function nor an Obj-C method. What you'll want to do is either follow @yan's suggestion and use a C function for you comparison or (my suggestion), don't bother using `qsort` at all, just use the `NSArray` methods to do your sorting.